Is there a way to reduce Largest Contentful Pain element Render delay for an image?
I have a  website that has a very small webp image. When I run the Pagespeed Insight I get this:
https://ibb.co/6swNZxJ
i don't know why the load and espacially the render delay is that high i am using litespeed cache but it is bot helping and it is dropping my pagespeed score by a lot
my website is :https://cansultadev.wpengine.com/

There are many images that are being loaded before the LFP image, which is what causes the delay. Because Elementor is being used, optimizing will be a difficult, uphill battle. Preloading your image using <link rel="preload"> is probably the best option, but challenging because Elementor doesn't expose it's data easily (dynamically populating the URL).
